# I don't have a problem [with] asking for help

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositions

I've looked into COCA for citations of "*problem asking for*" and "*problem **with** asking for*", and I found references to both. But I have a feeling that one is more common that the other or one is more informal than the other, so which is which?

> Example: I don't have a problem [with] asking for help from specific
>   people.

Comment: Let me guess (I didn't look it up yet), the one without "with" is more likely in spoken corpus (and thus implies the informality). Am I correct? :-)

Comment: I got one result for each, and both are from the same source, a magazine. So I can't tell. What I feel is that the one with "with" may not be formal (I'm confused anyway!).

Comment: I see now why I have to listen and read (and maybe write) a lot with "scanning English" in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two expressions overlap, but are not always interchangeable.

1. If you find it difficult to perform some action expressed as a verb you should ordinarily use the *-ing* form, thus:

   > I have a problem calculating derivatives.
   >   I have a problem asking for help.
2. If you find it difficult to perform in some matter expressed as a noun—an academic subject, for instance, or a category of action—use the preposition phrase headed by *with*:

   > I have a problem with calculus.
   >   I have a problem with relationships at work.
3. However, *to have a problem **with** X* can also have a different meaning: *to have an objection to X*. The idea expressed is not that X is difficult, but that it would create a difficulty—perhaps a practical difficulty, perhaps a moral or philosophical difficulty:

   > I have a problem with asking Herbert for help. Whenever you ask him for help on a project he tries to take it over and make it part of his empire building.

The lines between these can be fuzzy; but in general you should avoid using *with* with an *-ing* form unless you are speaking of your objection (3) rather than your incompetence (1).

Comment: A couple of minutes with NGrams suggests to me that the ***with** [gerund]* form is a relative newcomer. Which may or may not be related to the increased use of *have a problem with X = **object to** X* (where "with" can't be omitted). Personally, I would hardly ever include "with" except when the problem concerns *how I feel about X*. But then again, I suppose if I have intense negative feelings towards some [gerund-based] activity, it's quite likely I won't be any good at it, which might also be a problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They're both pretty new. The earliest use of *have a problem* followed by an *-ing* form I found in Google Books was 1912.